# MySQL Replication with Different Table Name & only specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, replication, database-replication, master-slave

I have below queries regarding MySQL replication.

1) Suppose i want to do master-slave replication with different table name then is it possible ?

> Ex. **Master >> Db1.student** i want to replicate with **Slave >> Db2.employee** table.

2) If i want to replicate only specific columns in same table then is it possible ?

> Master >> Db1.student
>
> - id
> - firstname
> - lastname
> - parentname
> - status
>
> Slave >> Db2.student
>
> - id
> - firstname
> - lastname

Apart from that is there any other way to achieve/solution above query (i.e MySQL Views) or any other alternate way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looking at [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), to show a subset of data. I suggest that you could create the view on the master and replicate the view instead of the complete table.

Comment: can i replicate only that view ?

Because i dont want to x'fer all my tables data to slave database as there is some sensitive data so i want to copy only specific columns data into slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eassiest way is to use a View like this:

```
CREATE VIEW Db2.student AS 
     SELECT id, firstname, lastname 
       FROM Db1.student;
```

If you want to filter some content in the Db2 view you could add some filters to the view creation. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW Db2.student AS 
     SELECT id, firstname, lastname 
       FROM Db1.student
      WHERE Db1.student.status = 1;
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Yes it is works but what if MySQL server is different ?

Also in same server 2 different users is there for DB1 & DB2 then also it will works ?

Comment: Then you should have to use federated tables. I've never had to used it. You can read some about this here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html

Comment: View will works for same server only. For different server i need to go for master-slave replication. 

Also in view, we need to give permission for specific table/column for that another DB user.